# Is it a requirement for an Android Go image to use f2fs format for data partition?

Tags: performance, android-10

I am currently performing performance testing using PCMark on a 2GB Ram Android Tablet but changing its OS (Android 10 vs 10 go). I have noted a considerable increase in storage performance (around 40%) and around 5% increase in CPU and Graphics processing performance.
I have been trying to find other differences between the two systems and found that the Android 10go image uses f2fs for data partition whilst Android 10´s one uses EXT4. This would explain the increase in storage performance...
Is using a f2fs format a requirement for an Android 10 go image?
My main goal is to confirm if it makes sense to make the switch.

Comment: You can use `f2fs` with almost any recent ROM. Recent kernel builds are also built with `f2fs` support.

Comment: Thanks, but is this a must for getting improved performance on Android Go?

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen such requirement documented anywhere. Also, as per my limited knowledge, F2FS was basically designed to be flash friendly (to reduce wear), not performance friendly. So under certain conditions EXT4 (or other filesystems) may perform better than F2FS.